# TYPO3 is not reading setup.txt or constants.txt of my extension

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I'm developing on 7.6 currently. I have made a few minor plugins that need to have their templates overridden for different pages, but I cant get TYPO3 to do this.

I have added static file include in `sys_template.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
    'my_contacts',
    'Configuration/TypoScript',
    'Main Template'
);
```

that contains `setup.txt` and `constants.txt`:

[image]

As you can see, I also added it in static.

**setup.txt**

```
plugin.my_contacts {
    view {
        templateRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Private/Templates/
            1 = {$plugin.my_contacts.view.templateRootPath}
        }

        partialRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Private/Partials/
            1 = {$plugin.my_contacts.view.partialRootPath}
        }

        layoutRootPaths {
            0 = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Private/Layouts/
            1 = {$plugin.my_contacts.view.layoutRootPath}
        }
    }

    settings {
        cssFile = {$plugin.my_contacts.settings.cssFile}
    }
}
```

**constants.txt**

```
plugin.my_contacts {
    view {
        # cat=plugin.my_contacts/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (FE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Private/Templates/
        # cat=plugin.my_contacts/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (FE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Private/Partials/
        # cat=plugin.my_contacts/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (FE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }

    settings {
        # cat=plugin.my_contacts/file; type=string; label=Path to CSS file
        cssFile = EXT:my_contacts/Resources/Public/Css/news-basic.css
    }
}
```

The contents used to be simple, but at this stage, I have them copied from `news` plugin, so it has now more settings, but I dont see those entries when I check the Template Analyzer or try to access settings in vew/controller. Also, when I try to override the template paths in a template content in a page, nothing happens there either.

The plugin Templates themselves are recognized and read, I just cant get them to be overridden (**or read settings from setup**).

[image]

I read lots of examples but cant find what I'm missing, so any hint is apreciated.

PS: Also, I have cleared all system caches and autoload information, just in case. Didnt help.

Comment: Use the TypoScript object browser to check if your settings are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now you have just registered the static Typoscripts for usage in Typoscript Templates. Please select your Typoscript Template using the "Template" module in the backend and go to "Edit whole Template record". On "Includes" you now see all extension that have registered static Typoscript like your extension and include them to your current Template. (see Screenshots below).

[image]
[image]

Comment: I like your images. But why do you suggest to use ext_tables.php? TYPO3 is moving everything out of ext_tables.php. ext_tables.php is not cached, files in  Configuration/TCA/Overrides/ are.

Comment: I'm not sure if it really good placed there since this is not a typical TCA configuration. But if it works in sys_templates.php too, then I you are right I guess. If it works it should better stay there.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, workday was over :) Thank you and I got it to work. One major thing, that I had to change was in `setup.txt` the value from `plugin.my_contacts {}` to `plugin.tx_mycontacts {}`. In `constants.txt` I left as it is. Now it works as intended, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the static template in your TypoScript template?

1. Open TYPO3 backend
2. Head to module "Template"
3. Select your home page
4. Select Info/Edit in the select box at the top
5. Click on the bottom button "Edit the whole template record"
6. Head to tab "Includes"
7. Head to field "Include static (from extensions)" and select your TypoScript. In your case it should be titled "Main template (my_contacts)"